# How to correlate two time series, with possible time differences

Tags: time-series, correlation

The question is similar to [How to correlate two time series with gaps and different time bases?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7727/how-to-correlate-two-time-series-with-gaps-and-different-time-bases) but with regular sample frequency and identical time base between two time series.

Say I have two time series, one is the stock price for a given company, the other is the ratio of positive comments about the company on social networks. How can I statistically verify that they are correlated? Assume they are both sampled weekly or daily. The challenge lies in the fact that there might be a time difference between each other. In the context of my example above, the positive evaluation from consumer might be later reflected on the stock price.

There are two things I want to investigate in this problem:

1. Are the two time series correlated?
2. What is the time window to maximize their correlation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apply a lag operator on one time series, with the other fixed, and calculate the coherence of the cross-spectrum achieved against each lag. Find the lag that gives you the maximum coherence and interpret it.

Coherence is computed at each frequency-and hence is a vector. Hence, a sum of a weighted coherence would be a good measure. You would typically want to weight the coherences at frequencies that have a high energy in the power spectral density. That way, you would be measuring the similarities at the frequencies that dominate the time series instead of weighting the coherence with a large weight, when the content of that frequency in the time series is negligible.

http://www.stat.rutgers.edu/home/rebecka/Stat565/lab5-2007.pdf is a good link to look at to get started and
http://www.atmos.washington.edu/~dennis/552_Notes_6c.pdf is an excellent introduction to cross-spectral analysis.

Comment: Any hints on how can I evaluate how strong is the coherence is? Is it possible to do t-test on the coherence of the cross-spectrum?

Comment: Coherence is computed at each frequency-and hence is a vector. Hence, a sum of a weighted coherence would be a good measure. You would typically want to weight the coherences at frequencies that have a high energy in the power spectral density. That way, you would be measuring the similarities at the frequencies that dominate the time series instead of weighting the coherence with a large weight,  when the content of that frequency in the time series is negligible. I added this in the answer above, after reading your comment. This is a good question.

Comment: Can coherence be calculated for each block, when the signals are divided into multiple overlapping blocks of equal length ? I tried it and I keep getting coherence of 1 for all frequencies in every block.

Answer (score 8):

The [cross correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation) function will give you the Pearson correlation for 2 time-series at different time lags. The R function is ccf().

For further study, a [Granger causality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granger_causality) test tries to determine a cause-effect relationship between the 2 correlated series by first removing the serial correlation in TS1 (the stock price series in this case).

Comment: Thanks. How does the cross correlation compared to the coherence of the cross-spectrum? In terms of statistical meaning, complexity, etc.

Comment: I can't answer that question, you might want to open a new thread for specific details.