# Time spans in coherence computation

Tags: r, time-series, spectral-analysis

Currently I'm writing my master thesis and I'm having troubles with coherence definition. My question is similar to [Clear steps to calculate coherence between two time series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92412/clear-steps-to-calculate-coherence-between-two-time-series)

Mathematically it's defined as

$$C_{xy}(\omega) = \displaystyle{\frac{|S_{xy}(\omega)|^2}{S_{xx}(\omega) S_{yy}(\omega)}} $$

where $S_{xy}$ is the cross-spectrum between $X$ and $Y$ and $S_{xx} \text{ and } S_{yy}$ the corresponding power spectra. However, when doing the math using the periodogram estimation

$$\hat{S}_{xy}(\omega) = \frac{1}{N} x(\omega) y^{*}(\omega)$$

(being $x(\omega)$ the DFT of $X$ and $y^{*}(\omega)$ the conjugated DFT of $Y$) everything cancels out and $C_{xy}$ turn to be $1$ for all $\omega$. This is where my question arises:

I'm using `seewave::coh` function from `R` to compute coherence, which calls `spec.pgram` function in this part of the source code:

`Y <- spec.pgram(cbind(wave1, wave2), fast = FALSE, taper = FALSE, 
        spans = c(3, 3), plot = FALSE)$coh`

I get that `spans` argument allows to avoid the "always 1 problem", but I don't get the "how". I would really appreciate if some of you could explain $\text{how}$ this works in the definition given above. Thank you so much.